# Multi select html and javascript value send from POST , GET

Tags: javascript, php, html

And enter Html select in another select but the second select does not send information either by GET or by POST. I don't know where I will add the id = "" and name = "" in JavaScript, to make it work.

```
<select id="type" name="type">
    <option value="item1">item1</option>
    <option value="item2">item2</option>
    <option value="item3">item3</option>
</select>

<select id="size">
    <option value="">-- select one -- </option>
</select>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#type").change(function() {
        var val = $(this).val();
        if (val == "item1") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item1: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item1: test 2</option>");
        } else if (val == "item2") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item2: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item2: test 2</option>");

        } else if (val == "item3") {
            $("#size").html("<option value='test'>item3: test 1</option><option value='test2'>item3: test 2</option>");

        }
    });


});                                 
</script>
```

With type it works, but it receives only the information of the first select

It is included in form. And the source code is this: http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "it works" I assume you mean these elements are part of a `<form>` which is being submitted at some later point?  The first `<select>` sends its value in that form because it has a `name`:

```
<select id="type" name="type">
```

The second `<select>` is missing its `name`, so a `<form>` has no way to include it.  Simply give it a `name`:

```
<select id="size" name="size">
```

Comment: It is included in form.
And the source code is this.
http://jsfiddle.net/YPsqQ/

Comment: @diaconuliviu: Then what exactly is the problem?  How is this failing?

Comment: is work , I didn't realize that javascript is associated with the second select